# Count the total value if the column in datagridview is not visible

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
 For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        fundwith += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Withdrawal").Value
        trans += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Trans").Value
        meal += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Meal").Value
        rep += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Rep").Value
        meet += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Meet").Value
        misc += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Misc").Value
        oth += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Others").Value
        inc += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Inc").Value
        dec += DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Dec").Value
    Next
```

I get this error "Operator '+' is not defined for type 'Double' and type 'DBNull'."

How do i get the total for Column Inc and Column Dec if those 2 column is not visible?

Comment: Does `inc` & `dec` columns actually contain data but invisible, or it is possible to just have DBNull on those columns?

Comment: thank you. now i know my error. the value is null that's why i'm getting the error.

Comment: I think you can check against DBNull and automatically converts it to `Double`'s default value (0), something like `inc += CheckDBNull(DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("Inc").Value)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the calculations on your data source instead. If your underlying source is a data table, you can enumerate through your data rows or use `table.compute`.

Answer (score 0):

Access the underlying `DataRow`...

```
Dim drw as DataRow = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(i).DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row
```

Then

```
fundwith += CDec(drw("Withdrawal")) 'replace CDec with whatever type conversion you need
```

Comment: While that's certainly not wrong, there's no actual need to access the `DataRow` from the `DataRowView` because the `DataRowView` can provide the same information.